# call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

Tags: jquery, android, html

I am using android phonegap to access html5 into android application. While I am running android application Logcat is showing the following error E/libEGL(614): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread). Though I restarted eclipse and emulator,same error is showing. Helping Hands are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You get this error when trying to do hardware accelerated stuff such as css3 transitions. you have to enable hardware acceleration for your app in the manifest file.

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

Comment: This did not work in my case. And I also specified the GL version in the manifest AND added it to the activity. More suggestions?

Comment: Found cause...Sencha Touch 2 CSS3 loading indicators firing too early.